# Miss translation in spree commerce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

After translate my spree project to pt-Br, is appearing this in taxonomy page "translation missing: pt-BR.spree.taxonomy_brands_name". 
Someone can help me to solve this?

Comment: Image of the problem -> http://imgur.com/57cDPUP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this making a configuration in nameProject/locales/pt-BR.yml
[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hy41E.png)